# Having problems while registering data to json only registers numbers and not string

Tags: python, json, string, async-await, discord.py

So hello as for some information my JSON file name is `pokemon.json` and it registers the user with no errors but I need to send in strings like if I type .pick charmander it will send the stats of charmander into my JSON file but it only sends in this:

```
"{ "user id" : {pokemon : 0} }"
```

also for more information this is the error im getting and the code is below the error too :

```
Ignoring exception in command pick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 102, in pick
    users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"]("name : Charmander, attack : {attack} ,defense : {defense} ,speed : {speed} ,special attack : {specialatk} ,special defense : {specialdef} ,gender : {gender} ,iv : {iv}")
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Now the code :

```python
import discord
import discord.ext
import webserver
import json
import random
from webserver import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user}'.format(client) , 'is now online')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="with pokemons"))

@client.command(name='fact')
async def facts(ctx):
  await ctx.send("sticky leaf is gae")

@client.command(name='bal')
async def balance(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  users = await get_bank_data()
  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] 
  em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}'s balance",color = discord.Color.blue())
  em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
  
  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command(name='beg')
async def beg(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  users = await get_bank_data()
  earnings = random.randrange(200)
  await ctx.send(f"someone gave you {earnings} coins")
  users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
  with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      users = json.dump(users,f)

@client.command(name='invite')
async def invite(ctx):
 await ctx.send("https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=REDACTED&permissions=8&scope=bot")

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    if str(user.id) in users:
      return False
    else:
      users[str(user.id)]={}
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]=0
      with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
        return True

async def get_bank_data():
   with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    return users

@client.command(name="start")
async def start(ctx):
  em = discord.Embed(title = "Start your journey by choosing a pokemon",color=discord.Color.green())
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 1 starters" ,value = "Bulbasaur , Squirtle , Charmander")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 2 starters", value = "Chikorita , Totodile , Cyndaquil")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 3 starters", value = "Treeko , Mudkip , Torchic")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 4 starters", value = "Turtwig , Piplup , Chimchar")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 5 starters", value = "Snivy , Oshawott , Tepig")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 6 starters", value = "Chespin , Froakie , Fennekin")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 7 starters", value = "Rowlet , Popplio , Litten")
  em.add_field(name = "Gen 8 starters", value = "Grookey , Sobble , Scorbunny")
  await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command(name="pick")
async def pick(ctx,arg):
  await open_account_poke(ctx.author)
  users = await get_poke_data()
  user = ctx.author
  if arg == "Charmander" or "charmander":
    with open("pokemon.json","r") as f:
      json.load(f)
      iv = random.randrange(40,100)
      male_female = ["male","female"]
      gender = random.choice(male_female)
      attack = random.randrange(100,500)
      speed = random.randrange(100,500)
      defense = random.randrange(100,500)
      specialdef = random.randrange(100,500)
      specialatk = random.randrange(100,500)
      level = 5
      users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"]("name : Charmander, attack : {attack} ,defense : {defense} ,speed : {speed} ,special attack : {specialatk} ,special defense : {specialdef} ,gender : {gender} ,iv : {iv}")
      with open("pokemon.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users , f)
      await ctx.send("You have choosen charmander")

async def open_account_poke(user):
    users = await get_poke_data()
    if str(user.id) in users:
      return False
    else:
      users[str(user.id)]={}
      users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"]=0
      with open("pokemon.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
        return True

async def get_poke_data():
   with open("pokemon.json","r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    return users

keep_alive()
client.run('ignore this ')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```py
      users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"]("name : Charmander, attack : {attack} ,defense : {defense} ,speed : {speed} ,special attack : {specialatk} ,special defense : {specialdef} ,gender : {gender} ,iv : {iv}")
```

Is invalid syntax. I'm assuming you are trying to creation a dictionary, which should look like this:

```py
users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"] = {"name": "Charmander", "attack": attack, "defense": defense, "speed": speed, "special attack": specialatk, "special defense": specialdef, "gender": gender, "iv": iv}
```

`json.load` will then serialise it into JSON formatting and write it to your json file.

To give a little more detail, the reason why you get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` is because it thinks you are trying to execute a function stored at `users[str(user.id)]["pokemon"]` as you put parentheses next to it with a string as an argument.

If you want to read more about dictionaries in python, you can visit [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) link. And you can read more about how python handles json data [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_python_example.htm).